# Intializing ERC20 token using payable constructor from another function of different contract

Tags: erc-20, payable

I have an ERC20 contract which is deployed from another contract as following:

```
function createDao(string _tokenName) public payable returns (address tokenAddress) {
    tokenNumberIndex = safeAdd(tokenNumberIndex, 1);
    string memory _tokenSymbol = bytes32ToString(bytes32(tokenNumberIndex));
    address _tokenAddress = new REP(_tokenSymbol, _tokenName);
    erc20SymbolAddresses[_tokenSymbol] = _tokenAddress;
    return _tokenAddress;
}
```

The ERC20 contract is as following:

```
contract REP is ERC20Interface, Owned, SafeMath {
string public symbol;
string public  name;
uint8 public decimals;
uint public _totalSupply;

mapping(address => uint) balances;
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;

constructor(string _tokenSymbol, string _name) public payable{
    symbol = _tokenSymbol;
    name = _name;
    decimals = 18;
    _totalSupply = msg.value;
    balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
    emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
}
```

}

My assumption is that since `createDao` function is `payable`, whatever is sent in `createDao` will be passed on to the ERC20 contract as msg.value. Though both the functions are payable, how do I pass on the value while initializing ERC20 token?

Answer (score 3):

By default, when you call `new REP()`, `msg.value` is not passed through, since the `msg` changes to the contract deployment.

You need to pass value explicitly, as described in [this](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#how-do-i-initialize-a-contract-with-only-a-specific-amount-of-wei) section of the documentation.

Try:

```
address _tokenAddress = (new REP).value(msg.value)("param1", "param2");
```

Comment: I am unable to change the value while confirming the transaction on calling createDao function in the other contract in Metamask. Can you help me on how I can pass a non-zero value ?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with metamask, sorry. I imagine you can set a value via web3 when building the tx for metamask.

Answer (score 0):

if you need only the amount of `msg.value`, pass another argument for `totalSupply` when initialing:

```
constructor(string _tokenSymbol, string _name, uint256 totalSupply) {
symbol = _tokenSymbol;
name = _name;
decimals = 18;
_totalSupply = totalSupply;
balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
}
```

then:

```
address _tokenAddress = new REP(_tokenSymbol, _tokenName, msg.value);
```

plz vote it up if it works properly :)